# Translation from <pthread.h> to <boost/thread.hpp>

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads

Can you please help me translate the following methods from the **pthread** library to **boost** library :

```
pthread_t tid; // I guess this should become : boost::thread tid; 
//... some instructions ...

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))process_request, (void*)some_ptr); 

void *process_request(void *soap) 
{ 
   pthread_detach(pthread_self()); 
   //... some instructions ...
   return NULL; 
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're asking for fairies and unicorns! There's no way to translate, these are completely different APIs!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for unfeasible things.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ are you annoyed that the OP doesn't show what he's done, or are you unaware that Boost Thread is effectively a fore-shadow of C++11 `<thread>` support?

Comment: I'm well aware what Boost Thread library is. I'm annoyed because a comparison of a C-API with a C++-API will be a clumsy approach. Well but your answer seems to contradict this ;).

Comment: I'm not looking for a translation "function by function". I'm looking for the right global translation that would give the same result, but using Boost library. Thanks.

Comment: @GotACrushOnIT I'm glad you say that, because detaching from within the thread function doesn't belong in that "right translation" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply:

```
boost::thread(&process_request, some_ptr).detach();
```

You can replace `boost` by `std` and your program is portable in c++11.

Note that `process_request` can actually take the parameter strong-typed now. If you want to pass a reference, use `boost::ref` (or `std::ref`, indeed):

```
void process_request(MyData& data)
{
}

MyData data;
boost::thread th(&process_request, boost::ref(data));
th.join();
```

It's a bit of a pattern in C++11, though, to *move* the data into the thread function, so as to avoid races on the parameters being passed:

```
void process_request(MyData&& data)
{
}

MyData data;
boost::thread th(&process_request, std::move(data));
th.join();
```

Comment: Hello! First of all thank you for your answer! +1. Well, I still have some couple confusions here : How to call the **detach()** method inside of **process_request** definition? Also, instead of using the constructor to set &process_request... is there a way for assigning? Because I have to declar **th** somewhere else. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sure, both with declaration and assignment separated, and with detach inside the thread function: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8839110cccccb432)**. Disclaimer: I think _both_ things are bad ideas. Use a thread_group, join > detach.

Comment: Perfect! I'm gonna give you a bounty tomorrow to distinguish your helpful answer!

Comment: And I think that it would be better that you edit your answer and to embed what you made in the link... To be explicitly clear to people who cross the same need and who reads ur answer. Thanks.